# Excel using a string as a cell reference

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to create a dynamic graph that checks which financial year it is and then only graph the data for that range of months.

I have a 'SUMMARY DATA' sheet that has rows with the date range 1/7/18 || 31/7/18 and so on for every month. I am trying to create a dynamic range that takes these values and then have the graph use those cell references.

Currently I am using a fancy concatenate function that gives me `'SUMMARY DATA'!$H$25:$H$36` (In cell `DASHBOARD!$AJ$24`) which is the range that I want to reference. I can't seem to get this working with a graph though. If I place `=DASHBOARD!$AJ$24` as the series values, the graph doesn't update with the correct values (just 0 for every column). If I try using `=INDIRECT(DASHBOARD!$AJ$24)`, it gives me a "That function isn't valid" error.

Not sure how to progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a named range (Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager) called cdata with a Refers to: of,

```
=indirect(DASHBOARD!$AJ$24)
```

Now use `=Dashboard!cdata` as the chart data source.

Be advised that these series data references are resolved; they do not stay dynamic. i.e. changing the reference in DASHBOARD!$AJ$24 does not automatically alter the chart data.

Comment: Perfect. It works, but is there a way to make it dynamic? Whilst the value would only change every 6-12 months, it would still be nice to have it update when needed

Comment: I typically use vba to reassign a range to the data series. Record yourself performing the action and then edit the code to suit your purposes.

Comment: A worksheet_change event sub based on changes in DASHBOARD!$AJ$24 should do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be editing the named range so that it recalculates? Isn't that how I would get it to reset?

Comment: No, a worksheet_change event sub based on changes in DASHBOARD!$AJ$24 will eliminate the need for the interim named range.